# CMake FetchContent for aggregated library

Tags: c++, git, cmake

There is specific case with cmake FetchContent.

I'll try to describe this based on projects in official cmake documentation [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#typical-case)
there are two simple examples with gtest and catch2.

Suppose that I've created my own git repo which contains simple cmakelists like this

```
project(my_super_lib)

add_subdirectory(googletest)
add_subdirectory(catch2)
```

and have put both known testing libs source into subfolders in my repo.

In my project, I've added this

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
       my_super_lib
       GIT_REPOSITORY https://myhosting.repo/my_super_lib.git
       GIT_TAG   "master"
 )

 FetchContent_MakeAvailable(my_super_lib)
```

after that, I need to use usual way to find packages inside my application cmakelists, suppose to make available sub libs from outside

```
 find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
```

but it doesn't work. any idea how to call Declare to make sub-libs inside available for find package ?

also common question about FetchContent procedure - e.g. one of real library CLI11, as I understand ConfigCLI1.cmake script will be ready to use after the build only, so find_package (CLI11 REQUIRED) will be incorrect in all cases because it executes on config stage but available on build stage.

probably only valid way is do not use find_package but use add_subdirectory  for just downloaded external projects instead?...